# How come I have so many hops when I traceroute my local ip

Tags: routes, ip, osx-mavericks, traceroute

My local ip is 192.168.1.106 and when I list my routing table it suggests that it is the case.
When I traceroute to 192.168.1.106 it states that there are 64 hops.

Should it not be zero hops?

```
localhost:~ cram$ netstat -rn
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            192.168.1.1        UGSc           37       33     en1
127                127.0.0.1          UCS             0        0     lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH             27    38597     lo0
169.254            link#5             UCS             0        0     en1
192.168.1          link#5             UCS             4        0     en1
192.168.1.1        48:f8:b3:73:7f:23  UHLWIir        27        5     en1   1199
192.168.1.106      127.0.0.1          UHS             6       56     lo0
192.168.1.131      0:90:a9:bd:5:73    UHLWIi          1        2     en1   1195


localhost:~ cram$ traceroute 192.168.1.106
traceroute to 192.168.1.106 (192.168.1.106), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
```

Comment: You didn't actually show the whole `traceroute` output that would show how many hops were taken.  There should be one line per hop.  The header output just says that `traceroute` will display a *maximum* of 64 hops.  And this question is really off-topic for Stackoverflow.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, I misread your question.  Your local host is different.  Your local host should be 127.0.0.1.  I'm going to guess that the NIC gets a message request from the OS that it passes at the hardware level, this ticks the counter as a successful hand-off, then the network layer responds back with its IP address (your assigned IP).  Local host is defined as a software loopback.